# Docker won't startup

Tags: docker

If I try to start docker server like so:

```
systemctl start docker
```

I get:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running:

```
systemctl status docker.service
```

Shows:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor p>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-04 03:25:10 EDT; 36s >
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 84866 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/F>
   Main PID: 84866 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
lines 1-7/7 (END)...skipping...
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-04 03:25:10 EDT; 36s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 84866 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 84866 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I'm on Solus linux and installed docker normally like `sudo eopkg install docker`. How should I go about trying to get it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a Solus linux specific issue due to an update. I fixed it by running `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/overlay` as suggested [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/SolusProject/comments/dlvtzn/docker_broken_for_anyone_else/) (the issue is tracked [here](https://dev.getsol.us/D7356)).

Comment: Why does that help? Could you summarize the link in case it stops working in the future?

Comment: Did not fix the issue for me.